# Is there an effective way to increase affection without Pokemon-Amie?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I have heard that having high affection will ultimately pay off, but having to take long breaks to do both Super Training an Pokemon Amie (both have vital bonuses, but take ages to make a difference) gets in the way of me enjoying the game. So, I would like to know whether affection can be gained through actions like using the pokemon in battle, using them in wireless battles (if regular battles don't work), leveling them up, healing them with potions or berries, or something else I haven't even thought of. (Also, are any of these actually effective methods, where affection gained per time spent is better than using Pokemon Amie (like, if it has a marginal increase and takes hours, I wouldn't consider it a viable alternative, but still mention it just in case).

Here is a related question, dealing with the bonuses friendship will give: [What bonuses are related to friendship?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136784/what-bonuses-are-related-to-friendship)

Comment: I always thought affection in Amie and affection (that decreases when the Pokémon faints, aka. *friendship*) are different. After all, Eevee evolves to Sylveon through Amie-affection, while "normal" affection (friendship) makes it evolve to Espeon at day, or Umbreon at night. But the conditions for Eevee to evolve into Sylveon are currently conflicting, so maybe I'm just mistaken.

Comment: @Nolonar very interesting, I hadn't ever thought of that. It makes sense though that friendship and affection are different values, because in real life, I wouldn't trust you as a battle partner if you gave me a bunch of candy, now would I?

Comment: I would, but only if you gave me cookies instead of candy :p

Comment: @TheUgly I removed your other two questions, as we try to keep one-question per question (and one-answer per answer.) Feel free to ask new questions, tho!

Comment: @Nolonar Sylveon also requires Eevee to have a fairy type move learned and then the affection is what affects it I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is not effective way to increase affection without Pokemon Amie. You can do it by using them in battles more and using potions on them but it is more efficient to use Pokemon Amie.

Comment: Battling and item use raises happiness, which is a distinct stat from affection. Happiness was present in previous generations and was used to evolve Eevee into Espeon/Umbreon, as well as other evolutions.

Comment: @yuki Happiness is **still** a mechanic in Gen VI, as can be seen by the continued existence of mechanics that rely on it, such as evolutions and the moves Return/Frustration.

Comment: @user3033745 I'm not saying that Happiness doesn't exist. I'm distinguishing it from *Affection*, which is a new stat introduced in Gen VI. It's a common misconception (or at least used to be) that Happiness == Affection, which is untrue.

Comment: @yuki It was how you phrased it that made me think that. "Happiness **was present in previous generations**...". Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Using them in battles more increases *friendship*, not affection, and using potions on them does nothing. Once you have two hearts on a pokemon's affection, you can pet them after they defeat another pokemon in battle, which *does* increase affection.