# What bonuses are related to friendship?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

If you battle with your pokemon, you increase your friendship with that pokemon. It wouldn't make sense to have a feature like that if it didn't change anything, but if I ever knew what bonus you got when gaining your pokemons' trust, I've forgotten. What bonuses are gained when you gain the trust of your pokemon, by battling and training them?

Comment: There are three things that come to mind. 1: Some Pokémon only evolve after you maximize friendship. 2: The [Return move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Return_%28move%29), which becomes stronger the more your Pokémon likes you. 3: The [Frustration move](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Frustration_%28move%29), which becomes stronger the more your Pokémon *hates* you. That's all I can think of right now.

Comment: As of gen VI, high friendship pokemon also do other things. Researching now.

Comment: Oh darn. Now I can't choose between Fogolicious and Studoku... Well, I'll have to think about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about just friendship then yes @Studoku's answer is correct but if you meant the new mechanic in X and Y called Affection, that is a little different.

- Resistant to having stats lowered
- Evasiveness increases
- Similar effect to Endure where stays at 1 hp
- Pokemon levels faster
- More critical hits( says something like ‘Pokemon Meowth is in sync with Trainer Name’)

All of these are permanent when there Affection is full as well, I do believe.

Comment: Ok, @Studoku 's answer is also very very good, but because I can only accept one answer, I have to choose this one because it mentions that affinity is a different concept than friendship, but please make sure to check Studoku's too!

Answer (score 4):

There are several effects of having a high friendship.

1. Certain pokemon such as Togepi are evolved by raising their friendship.
2. The move *Return*, which can be taught to anything which can learn TMs has power based on the friendship stat of the user. Its power reaches 102 at max friendship, often making it the strongest Normal move a pokemon can learn. *Frustation*, the opposite of Return, has power based on how low the user's friendship is.
3. As of Gen VI, an extremely high friendship has other effects in battle. The full effects and chances haven't been fully discovered yet but the effects of extremely loyal pokemon include.

   - Surviving moves that would otherwise KO
   - Recovering from Status Effects
   - Increased Critical chance

Comment: I think only two hearts (instead of max) friendship is necessary for friendship evolution too.